# DBCP connection pool connection spawning

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons-dbcp

Please help me understand hot the DBCP will work when multiple threads will try to use same connection?

A new connection will be spawned for every thread? And in this case there will be no advantage to use connection pool.

Comment: Please give more deatlis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC `Connection` is by definition single-threaded. When one thread obtains connection from `DataSource` (DBCP or any other implementation), no other thread can touch that connection until it is released (closed, which actually puts the connection back into the pool).

DBCP won't prevent using the same connection from multiple threads. But if multiple threads ask `DataSource` for new connection at the same time, it will create as many connections as needed. If the number of concurrent threads exceeds max configured connections allowed to be spawned, `getConnection()` will block or fail.

Comment: Also when the connection gets put back in the pool, it may be reused by another thread (or another request) when it requests a connection later on. If a connection is reused, it doesn't need to incur the setup time and the whole database thing works, on average, faster.